# Where Clause - When date is selected also include blanks

Tags: sql, date, conditional-statements, where-clause

```
WHERE
    lipLifeQuoteAppDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    AND lipLifeQuoteEUdate IS NULL
    AND casCurrentWorkflowID <900
    AND lipStatus <> 'Not proceeding'
    AND lipLifeQuoteCallDate  < @LatestCallDate
```

---

I've attached only the where clause from one of my scripts, the problem is on the last line. This script brings out a list of applications between the date range "**lipLifeQuoteAppDate**"

The field called "**lipLifeQuoteCallDate**" shows when a call was made to the client after an application was received.

E.g. John Smith makes an application on the 25th Jan (**lipLifeQuoteAppDate**), he was then called on the 1st Feb (**lipLifeQuoteCallDate**).

I want to select the applications between the 1st to the 31st Jan, then using (**lipLifeQuoteCallDate**) I want to then only show the cases which were contacted before the 31st January. This is what the script above does. The problem I have is that I've found out some of my fields in the second date range (**QuoteCallDate**) are blank how can I include them when somebody selects a date?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "blank" do you mean NULL?  Or more to the point, are your fields string (VARCHAR, etc) or real DATETIME data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean to test when `lipLifeQuoteCallDate IS NULL` and allow those values, even though NULL is not `< LatestCallDate`, you can try this...

```
WHERE lipLifeQuoteAppDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
  AND lipLifeQuoteEUdate IS NULL
  AND casCurrentWorkflowID < 900
  AND lipStatus <> 'Not proceeding'
  AND (lipLifeQuoteCallDate < @LatestCallDate OR lipLifeQuoteCallDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks Dems, I dropped in the code and it worked perfectly, before I posted I put in '' which of course didn't work I should have known to use IS NULL! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that a blank (null?) lipLifeQuoteCallDate counts as being before the date specified?  If so:

```
AND ((lipLifeQuoteCallDate < @LatestCallDate) or (lipLifeQuoteCallDate is null))
```